# Db Vis: how to visualise the data in Data Monitor with graphs?

Tags: macos, visualization, dbvisualizer

I have the AdventureWorks db in DbVis Free edition (OSX) and I want to visualise the data in Data monitor with graphs like below. I am not sure whether this [charts feature](https://www.dbvis.com/features/tour/charts/) is working only in Pro.

[image]

**How can I visualise the data with graphs like the below in Db Vis?**

*Goal to visualise the data with graphs like below.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charting support is available only in the DbVisualizer Pro edition. Read more how to setup [monitors](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG95/Monitoring+Data+Changes) and [charts](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG95/Working+with+Charts) in DbVisualizer Pro. You may evaluate the Pro edition by signing up in **Help->Evaluate Pro** Edition.

Comment: Does The license expire after an year? Do you DB Vis Pro is somehow superior to other alternatives such as SQL Server Management Studio? Do you think nonPro DBVis is insufficient? Experiences?

Comment: A license is perpetual and never expires with the versions that are released during a year after purchase. Using feature versions released after one year requires a license renewal. To answer your other questions, give it a try by evaluating it. Only you can tell whether it fullfils your requirements.